# Link Image to a Specific Field in a List

Tags: list, hyperlink

I have two lists:

- One has books available (content)
- and the other is to check out the available content (checkout).

In the content list, I have a field with the images of the book. I have also created a view in the content list that shows only the book images.

In the checkout list/form, I have a field that is set to the Book Title as a look-up field. I would like to add a hyperlink to the book image in the content list that directs them to the checkout list with the Book Title field already populated.

I know how to hyperlink to the checkout form, but is there a way to add a target of some sort to the hyperlink to populate the Book Title field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's correct, sorry I missed the 'lookup field' in your question.

- In this case, you can use an additional text column to store the value and populate the lookup Title.
- Create column, lets say TitleValue in Checkout List. Use this field in the connection to store the value.
- Use the below URL in the hyperlink, as it is a lookup field, it works with ID and not the field value.

  > `http://<CompleteListFormURL>?BookTitle=<ID>`
- Now, in the infopath form, create a rule on TitleValue Field. When the field changes, set the lookup field equals to TitleValue field (it will populate based on ID).
- Hide this TitleValue in the form, as it is not required to be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Have the checkout form as InfoPath.

- Open ListTools -> List -> Customize List -> Form WebParts -> New Form.
- Add Query String URL Filter. Edit the WebPart and give a name for Query String Parameter Name lets say BookTitle.
- Use the dropdown of WebPart properties, to add the connection to InfoPath WebPart Book Title column.

Now in the hyperlink, you can use

```
http://<CompleteListFormURL>?BookTitle=<TitleColumn>
```

This would open the form with the field populated.

Comment: Thanks! I'm still having some issues getting them to connect. When I make the web part connection in the form and go to do the connection, "Book Title" doesn't show up in the list to connect to QueryString. Is this because it's a look up field?